# I cannot get the a property of component(post) in the app component using Output and EventEmitter in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

it says argument of type any is not assignable.
Am I supposed to import something else in the app.component?
Could you please tell what am I doing wrong?
app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  posts=[];
  onAddedPost(post){
    this.posts.push(post)
  }
}
```

here is the problem. the post in onAddedPost is the problem.
post-create.component.ts

```js
import { sharedStylesheetJitUrl } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Output, OutputDecorator } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
  enteredContent='';
  enteredTitle='';
  @Output() postCreated = new EventEmitter();
  onAddPost(){
    const post={title:this.enteredTitle,content:this.enteredContent};
    this.postCreated.emit(post);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```js
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
<app-post-create (postCreated)="onPostAdded($event)" ></app-post-create>
<app-post-list [posts]="storedPosts"></app-post-list>
</main>
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
      HeaderComponent,
      PostListComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,

  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What if you try with `@Output() postCreated = new EventEmitter<any>();` (https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: it still says: Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: You have a typo, your app.component.html says `onPostAdded()` but your app.component.ts says `onAddedPost()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's a TSLint error since it couldn't infer the type. Note: this would not affect the app as compiled JS would not have sense of the TS types.

However to solve it you could define a Typescript Interface of the type.

1. Define a model

**post.ts**

```js
export interface Post {
  title?: string;
  content?: string;
}
```

2. Use this model to define type in both the components.

**post-create.component.ts**

```js
import { sharedStylesheetJitUrl } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Output, OutputDecorator } from '@angular/core';

import { Post } from './post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
  enteredContent='';
  enteredTitle='';

  @Output() postCreated: EventEmitter<Post> = new EventEmitter<Post>();

  onAddPost(){
    const post: Post = {
      title: this.enteredTitle,
      content: this.enteredContent
    };
    this.postCreated.emit(post);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Post } from './post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  posts: Post[] = [];

  onAddedPost(post: Post) {
    this.posts.push(post);
  }
}
```

Comment: oh heck... it is still the same when I try to run it.Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:15 - error TS7006: Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.

12   onAddedPost(post){

Comment: You could see the type is specified for the function parameter in the post: `onAddedPost(post: Post) {..`. You don't seem to have it from the error message.

Comment: I think I managed to get it to work somehow. Now I would like when I add a new post to display it. but it wont show up. In the app.component.html i have this: "<app-post-list [posts]="storedPosts" ></app-post-list>". And in the post-list.component.ts i have this: export class PostListComponent  {

  @Input() posts:Post[] = [];

}

Comment: That is separate question. I'd say this question has been solved and would recommend to open a new question.

Comment: sure! thank you very much for the help you provided for the previous question! have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a class Post and use it for your EventEmitter.

```
export class Post {
    title: string;
    content: string;
}

@Output() postCreated = new EventEmitter<Post>();
```

Comment: after I create that export class it gives this error.

Comment: class PostCreateComponent
Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.

Comment: instead of a `class` try `export interface Post`